# Can you mix up Client rendering and Server rendering for components in Nuxt.js similar to Next.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In Next.js you can have one component Static Side Rendered or Server Side Rendered and another component Client Side Rendered on the same page. Can you do the same in Nuxt.js? It seems I cannot find a proper answer.

Comment: It seems the question refers to a hybrid mode where you can have both SSG and SSR for the website.
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization. Nuxt does not have hybrid mode IIRC. It is either SSG or SSR.

Comment: @Kunukn really good point. We need to see what OP meant here but yeah, there is no SSG + SSR combo in Nuxt to my knowledge neither. Not sure if Nuxt Nitro will do that, it is more for Edge Rendering (SSR on serverless as I've understood).

Comment: Hi @vjori, any updates on what are you looking for?

Comment: @kissu Equivalent features of Next.js in Nuxt.js. In Next.js you can mix up 4 modes of rendering in a single page. I was wondering if Nuxt.js supported this feature for us that like Vue.js more than React.js.

Comment: Can you update your question with more details of the 4 modes? Also, are them available all at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your components are by default rendered on both: server + client (if your app is not SPA only of course).
For client side rendering only, you can use `<client-only>` as a wrapper as explained here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components/#the-client-only-component

There is **nothing** like `<server-only>` but you can prevent hydration with something like this: https://github.com/maoberlehner/vue-lazy-hydration

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid Rendering is coming soon to Nuxt 3, as the documentation mentions now: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/concepts/rendering/#hybrid-rendering

And there is also a GitHub discussion about that topic as well: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/560